# Click Once publishing project with .csv file references

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csv, clickonce

I am attempting to publish a .net framework application with click once. After installing the application, and attempting to run it, it fails to execute with no error message. However, I saw that some .csv files that are referenced within the program are not present in the "Application Files" portion of the publishing tab, while .txt files that are referenced, are present.

Within the program, these files are referenced like: "creditkey.txt". I have never published an application before, so I'm unsure if this filename will find any file correctly. Regardless, it seems like the .csv is excluded from the install.

[image: Solution Explorer]

[image: Publiher Apllication Files]

I have tried publishing and executing a similar project on the same .net framework, but with no external references, and it installs and executes correctly. So, I believe the problem lies in the reference to these files. Any recommendations?

Update: The issue was that the build action property of the csv files, where not set to content. after that was set, all works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer the `.csv` files have the "Build Action" property set to "Content", the "Copy to Output Directory" set to "Copy always", and they are set to "Include (Auto)" in the "Application Files" folder on the "Publish Tab".

When you double-click the "Setup" application that is downloaded, it successfully installs the program.

Comment: @Jiale Xue, please don't abuse backticks for emphasis.